# JS : from RGB Blue to RGB Red

Tags: javascript, css, math

I'm trying to convert RGB color from blue (`rgba(0,0,255)`) to red (`rgba(255,0,0)`) on `JS mouseenter`, **progressively**.

*So, each time the mouse enter an element, it "increments" its background color, from blue to green and then to red.*

**With a WIP live demo** : http://codepen.io/enguerranws/pen/ZQOBwe

Here's what I've done so far :

```
function onGridDone(){
  var gridders = document.querySelectorAll('.gridder');
  for(var i = 0; i < gridders.length; i++){
    gridders[i].addEventListener('mouseenter', onHover );
  }  
}
function onHover () {
  var currentColor = this.style.backgroundColor,
      currentColorArr = currentColor.replace(/[^\d,]/g, '').split(',');
      R = currentColorArr[0],
      G = currentColorArr[1],
      B = currentColorArr[2];
  console.log(R,G,B);
  if(B > 0) B = B-10;
  var indic = 255-B;
  G = indic/2;
  R = indic;

  this.style.backgroundColor = "rgb("+R+","+G+","+B+")";
}
```

I've tried multiple things, but basically, I want my color to go from `rgba(0,0,255)`, then `rgba(0,255,130)`, then `rgba(255,130,0)` and finally `rgba(255,0,0)` (so, from blue to green then green to red).

I know I could do multiple if/else statements to check each case, but I'm just wandering if there'is a more efficient way using maths ?

I'm not trying to do any animations / transitions.

Comment: Well the first problem is that you can't rely on the browser to give you the color back the same way as you set it. It'd be more reliable (and easier) to keep the current state somewhere separate from the style.

Comment: It's better to use css3 transitions or animations for that.

Comment: @jcubic how can I "increment" RGB values on mouse hover on transition / animation ?

Comment: Well, edited my question as it wasn't clear. I'm not trying to do an animation.

Comment: *"So, each time the mouse enter an element"* So you have `onHover` hooked to `mouseenter`? I'd show that.

Comment: Added full demo on codepen : http://codepen.io/enguerranws/pen/ZQOBwe

Comment: Added full code (most of it is non-relevant) on question.

Comment: Please leave the irrelevant part out. It's much easier to help you with the question if one doesn't have to look throgh the code to find the relevant part.

Comment: That's what I've done before. But as @T.J.Crowder asked me, I thought I should post it all. I removed the most irrelevant part.

Comment: @enguerranws Sorry, didn't read that. I think it's sufficient if all the code is accessible in the demo.

Comment: What you ask is possible using "maths" but it requires mapping a domain to a range, I. E. using if statements. I would make a traditional 'T-Chart' and map the values according to an iterator variable, and observe that there is no mathematical function that will produce the result you're looking for without using binary logic. (If statements)

Comment: @lex82: All **relevant** code must be **in the question**, not just linked. Links rot. So the right answer to "how are you hooking this up?" would be to show the code hooking it up, not link to a massive codepen.

Comment: @t-j-crowder I agree, all relevant code. I just asked to remove the irrelevant part because he explicitly stated that he had included irrelevant parts.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Well, what is relevant or not ? I have a function that create a grid of elements, so I consider it as non-relevant here and removed it from the code part, as my issue is not about this function.

Comment: How you call/hook up `onHover` is relevant. I'd say other than that, I'd say everything *else* was in your initial question. That's why I asked that one question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make use of a mathematical formula, it is helpful to have some numeric indicator of progress, e.g., from 0 to 255 and then calculate the colors from that.

It is not exactly what you "basically" asked for but it illustrates what I mean: Let's say the red component would increase linearly from 0 to 255 during the process. Then you could look at an existing field's red value and know immediately where you are. If you wanted to move through green, this should be close to what you want to do:

```
// assume r,g,b are the current values
var progress = r;
progress += 1; // of course you can increment faster
r = progress;
g = 255 - (255 * (Math.abs(progress-127)/128))
b = 255 - progress;
```

This way you will not pass the color `rgba(255,130,0)` as in your question. However, I think it might still solve your problem. `r` increases linearly, `b` decreases linearly and `g` first increases and then decreases after 50% of the process.

Comment: Very close. And I refrained from posting a similar answer due to the lack of exactness of applicability to his question, but this is essentially what must be done. As a side comment, I would use "x", "n", or "i" as the incremental variable since traditional mathematics is now the context of the situation

Comment: Seems to be what I'm looking for. I'm having issue implementing it : http://codepen.io/enguerranws/pen/ZQOBwe As you can see, progress always start at 0 so its max is 5 (assuming progress += 5).

Comment: Make sure you convert your strings to ints properly and vice versa! You need a parseInt() on the R and a Math.floor() on the G before you set the color.

Comment: That was it, forgot the Math.floor() so I was having decimals on G.

Comment: Updated my code : http://codepen.io/enguerranws/pen/ZQOBwe This solution seems more elegant and readable than the last if/elseif/whatever I putted before.